# Некорректно работает UPDATE() в sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

Здраствуйте, у меня возникла одна проблема. Когда я выполняю эту команду:

```
self.sql.execute('UPDATE nof SET tixt=?  WHERE id=?',(txt,ids,))
```

То текст не записывается, если вам нужен полный код то вот он:

```
import sqlite3
class db(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
        self.sql = self.db.cursor()
    def execute(self,text,args=None):
        if args is None:
            self.sql.execute(text)
        else:
            self.sql.execute(text,args)
        self.db.commit()
        return self.sql
    def update(self,txt,ids):
        self.sql.execute('UPDATE nof SET tixt=?  WHERE id=?',(txt,ids,))
        self.db.commit()
        return self.sql
    def __del__(self):
        self.db.close()
```

Вот фрагмент кода который всё это запускает

```
def EndStepNof(message):
sql = database.db()
wq = sql.update(message.text,message.from_user.id)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, dialogs['nofYes'],parse_mode=config.nofMode)
```

[image]
(Если что тут всё записывается кроме `tixt`)
Это доказательство что я прописал, столбик `tixt` при создание БД 
Спасибо за внимание! Буду рад любой помощи.
Только сейчас заметил что иногда-то при попытке запуска скрипта вылетает ошибка

> "19:30    Error running 'logic': Unexpected content storage modification:
> page=42; newRecord=14532"

но она в *event log* появилась

Прошу прощение у всех, я просто перепутал, и место ид в начале записывал время

Comment: в ids содержится один id или несколько? Работает ли, если передать ровно один id?

Comment: В ids передаeться один id.Щас дополню в основной части.

Comment: В таблице `nof` точно есть строки с этим id?

Comment: Да! Проверил дважды.

Comment: а если получать self.db.cursor() не единожды (кто знает, что с ним происходит после self.db.commit() - вот я не знаю), а перед запросом?

Comment: Я вас не понял. Объясните пожалуйста подробнее что мне сделать.

Comment: не. мимо. я не знаю что происходит с курсом если вызвать db.commit(), но попробовал и...ничего не происходит - курсор остается работоспособным